# I want to retrieve data of user from the 4 table in MySQL. How it is possible?

Tags: sql

How can I retrieve Student details from the 4four table?

Standard Table

```
stdID    stdName     stdImage
  1        IT        imgUrl1
  2       MscIT      imgUrl2
  3        BCA       imgUrl3
  4        MCA       imgUrl4
```

Subject table

```
subID    subName     stdID
 101       CPP         1
 102       C++         1
 103       .Net        2
 104       PHP         2
 105       iOS         3
 106     Android       3
 107      NodeJS       4
 108      ReactJS      4
```

Student Table

```
studID   studName  studGender  contact  stdID
 1001      ABC       male    1010101010   1
 1002      PQR      female   2020202020   2
 1003      XYZ       male    3030303030   3
```

table Student Subject

```
SSID   studID   subID
 11     1001     101
 12     1001     102
 13     1002     104
 14     1003     105
 15     1003     106
```

Want 1001 student data like this

```
studID   studName  studGender  contact  stdID stdName Subjects
1001     ABC       male        101010   1        IT    CPP,C++
```

I try using this Query but in the output all subjects are display

```
SELECT tblStudent.*, tblStandard.stdName,GROUP_CONCAT(tblSubject.subName,',') AS subjects 
FROM tblStudent 
INNER JOIN tblStandard ON tblStudent.stdID = tblStandard.stdID 
INNER JOIN tblStudentSubject ON tblStudent.studID = tblStudentSubject.studID
INNER JOIN tblSubject ON tblStudentSubject.subID = tblSubject.subID
GROUP BY tblStudent.studID
```

Comment: Incomplete grouping. `tblStandard.stdName` must be either removed from the output or added to GROUP BY expression. PS. `tblStudent.studID` is PK/UNIQUE, is it?

Comment: @Akina My query gives me the correct output. I made a mistake adding a record in my tblStudentSubject table.

Comment: *My query gives me the correct output.* It is temporary... until the server administrator alters SQL mode. Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and ensure.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT tblStudent.*, tblStandard.stdName,GROUP_CONCAT(tblSubject.subName,',') AS subjects 
FROM tblStudent 
INNER JOIN tblStandard ON tblStudent.stdID = tblStandard.stdID 
INNER JOIN tblStudentSubject ON tblStudent.studID = tblStudentSubject.studID
INNER JOIN tblSubject ON tblStudentSubject.subID = tblSubject.subID
GROUP BY tblStudent.studID
```

Is the output of my query.

[image]